# Clear web pages cache in jboss

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss6.x, exploded

I develop a web app:

- frontend javascript
- transport json
- backend Java EE
- JBoss AS 6.1

All static html and js files are in an exploded .war directory which itself is in an exploded .ear directory.

Normally everything works fine! Today I changed a html file and copied it to the .war directory.

When the browser loaded the file it was the old one. So I started wireshark and saw in wireshark the get request and the returned OLD file, even when I changed the filename in the .war directory.

So there is some caching in jboss. I started Googling and found some posts about the tmp and work folders.

I looked in my "...\server\default\work..." folders, but everything was empty.
In "...\server\default\tmp" I found some files but no one seems to be related to my cached page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a tomcat-in-jboss issue, you have to go to the tomcat area in jboss.
In my case `..\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar`. In this directory you should find a file called `context.xml`.

Now stop jboss.

In the `context` tag there are 2 attributes - `cookies` and `crossContext`. Now just add the attribute `cachingAllowed="false"` and start jboss again:

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true" cachingAllowed="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one time solution, just create fresh ear with fixed HTML file, undeploy the old one and deploy the new one.