# not able to publish xhtml changes to Jboss as 7.1.1 without redeplying to server

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jboss7.x, hotswap

I am using **Jboss 7.1.1 AS** to deploy my `JSF` based Web app. I am using [Filesync](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/) plugin to Hot swap the code. It's working perfectly fine for `.java` or `any other file`changes. But `Jboss as` not picking up the changes when I modify something in the `.xhtml` pages.

I tried by adding

```xml
 <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

to `web.xml`. But it's not working either and I don't see my changes in browser when I refresh the page. It worked with `tomcat` when I used same configuration. Do I need to do any special configuration for `Jboss` in order to make this work?

Comment: You dont need any special configuration.It is working for me.Change 2 value of refresh_period and try again.

Comment: @mstzn..Yeah I tried with -1 or 1 or 2 but neither of it is working. Are you working on `Jboss 7.1.1`?

Comment: yes i use JBoss 7.1.1.Final

Comment: @mstzn...ok. Let me try once again then.

Comment: Have you checked file timestamp on disks ? What are operating systems and file systems used ?

Comment: On Windows with anti-virus hooks for file checking, a network file system or NTFS are not the best options :) On Linux, you may have file permissions issues...

Comment: How the application archive is deployed - XML configuration block, standalone or domain, file locations... ? And how Filesync is configured ?

Comment: @YvesMartin....I am doing standalone deployment to my local machine. I am using Red hat linux workstation. I been using filesync with `Tomcat` for more than year with no issues. But the problem started with JBoss. Here also `.java` and other config files are working except `.xhtml`,`.js`and `.css`. I am using `Maven multi module` to build my project into ear and using maven pulgin to deploy it to the Jboss. Does that cause any issue?

Comment: Try adding <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param> in web.xml

Comment: @AdrianMitev... I forgot to post here but I have already added this peice in `web.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find the Issue with my Hot Deployment to Jboss server. It's not the Server Issue. But , it is the fact that I am using [Jboss Maven Plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) to deploy my application to Jboss , Hot deployment is not working. But if do regular deployment like

> `Application--->Run on Server`

my hot deployment is workng fine.  Not sure what's issue caused by Maven plugin

Answer (score 4):

Check if your configuration of [file synchronization](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/examples.html) is configured to include .xhtml files.

Take a look at [this article](http://entjavastuff.blogspot.com/2010/11/hot-deploying-from-eclipse.html).

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> ...
>
> Problem: files in the resources directories aren't synced
>
> Solution: for some reason, sometimes Eclipse wants to exclude all
>   files in the resources directories by default. Check this in the build
>   path of your project settings.

Other thing to check is, if .xhtml file has changed timestamp in **target** directory after it has been modified.

- If timestamp is changed after modification, than filesync is doing its
  job, but jboss is not reloading files.
- If timestamp is not changed, then filesync is not updating target
  dir. In this case configuration of filesync is the place to search
  for problem.

Comment: Yeah I set up everything included.Mine is `Maven multi module`. Does that cause any problem when using file sync?

Answer (score 2):

I think the keyword here is **cache**.

I'm not using Jboss AS or hotdeploy, but I faced the same problem with *JRebel* + *Thymeleaf* (template plugin).

The root of my problem was Thymeleaf's cache. Where were an option for caching templates in Thymeleaf and JRebel didn't know how to work with it.

So you need to find how *JBoss AS* caching this pages and to turn off this cache.

One of possible cases was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940254/1430055).

Comment: .......Thanks for bringing up the excellent point.I haven't thought about this scenrio. I will see whether this is affecting my case.

Answer (score -1):

put this in your web.xml

`<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>1</param-value>
 </context-param>`

I used to have this problem and it was useful for me

Comment: OP already used that (on JSF 1.x name) and OP has technically a different problem than you.

Comment: sorry i try this with  JSF 2.2  on widely 8.2